# Can we convert tree to doubly linked list using preorder or postorder traversal instead of inorder traversal?

Tags: c++, tree, doubly-linked-list, tree-traversal, preorder

**Conversion using inorder traversal**
Here we are traversing the tree in inorder fashion and changing it's left and right pointer to next and previous.

```
// A C++ program for in-place conversion of Binary Tree to DLL
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
/* A binary tree node has data, and left and right pointers */
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

// A simple recursive function to convert a given Binary tree to Doubly
// Linked List
// root --> Root of Binary Tree
// head --> Pointer to head node of created doubly linked list
void BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(node *root, node **head)
{
    // Base case
    if (root == NULL) return;
// Initialize previously visited node as NULL. This is
// static so that the same value is accessible in all recursive
// calls
static node* prev = NULL;

// Recursively convert left subtree
BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(root->left, head);

// Now convert this node
if (prev == NULL)
    *head = root;
else
{
    root->left = prev;
    prev->right = root;
}
prev = root;

// Finally convert right subtree
BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(root->right, head);
}

/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
node* newNode(int data)
{
    node* new_node = new node;
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
    return (new_node);
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given doubly linked list */
void printList(node *node)
{
    while (node!=NULL)
    {
        cout << node->data << " ";
        node = node->right;
    }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions*/
int main()
{
    // Let us create the tree shown in above diagram
    node *root   = newNode(10);
    root->left   = newNode(12);
    root->right  = newNode(15);
    root->left->left = newNode(25);
    root->left->right = newNode(30);
    root->right->left = newNode(36);

    // Convert to DLL
    node *head = NULL;
    BinaryTree2DoubleLinkedList(root, &head);

    // Print the converted list
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

If the interviewer asks is it possible to make list in a preorder or postorder fashion. What would be the
answer?
If yes then how?
I think we can traverse the tree in a preorder fashion and make a doubly linked list out of it. But how do I explain it to her.